# Beginner's Question on Type Casting

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, static-cast

I was going to use math.h on my numbers in my random number generator. It seems that I can only use the math.h functions on doubles. So:

I am trying to give "value" the value of "currentValue", or at least part of the number's value to be transferred over. I am working with a random number generator, so I do not care if the entire number is transferred. I only need part of it to work.

I have at some point:

```
int currentValue;
double value;
```

** Through code not shown their values are set. **

Later, I need part of value to go to currentValue.

```
currentValue = value
```

I tried:

```
currentValue = static_cast<int>value;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help. The problem is solved.

Comment: Please format your code properly (see the http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  That will ensure all the symbols appear correctly, and make your question more readable.  Also, the lone phrase **"it doesn't work"** is typically loathed upon -- be specific about the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the parens:

```
currentValue = static_cast<int>(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a cast when you don't need one.  [The code works perfectly fine with no cast at all.](http://ideone.com/P7GZl)